# Redshift - How to SUM number over last 4 weeks as a window function per row?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

is it possible to SUM a number over a special time period in Amazon Redshift with a WINDOW-Function?

As an example I'm counting login numbers for different companies per day. 
What I now want per row is, that it sums up the logins over the last 4 weeks (referenced by the date of the row): The field which I'm serarching for is marked yellow in the screenshot.

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have data for each day, then you can use `rows`:

```
select t.*,
       sum(logs) over (partition by company
                       order by date
                       rows between 27 preceding and current row
                      ) as logins_4_weeks
from t;
```

Redshift does not yet support `range` for the window frame, so this is your best bet.

Comment: Thanks Gordon - I'm making sure that we have data for every day (cross join into time dimension) so this solution will work.